# Jmeter beanshell Sampler_ Getting Error invoking bsh method

Tags: java, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

can we use vars.put to add the members of array list?

Below is my code which is throwing exception at at line 10, column 25 
and error is:

> Error invoking bsh method: eval   In file: inline evaluation of:
>   ``import java.util.List; import java.util.ArrayList; public static
>   void main(Strin . . . '' Encountered "vars" at line 10, column 25.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public static void main(String[] ard)
{
    String OperationNme = ${op};
    String[] serviceTypeVal = {12,19,20,21,22,23,26,27,28,31,32,11};
    String serviceType;
    switch (OperationNme) {
            case 1:  OperationNme.contains("sdv")
                     vars.put("serviceType",serviceTypeVal[0]);
                     break;
            case 2:  OperationNme.contains("doorUnlock")
                     vars.put("serviceType",serviceTypeVal[1]);
                     break;
            case 3:  OperationNme.contains("doorLock")
                     vars.put("serviceType",serviceTypeVal[2]);
                     break;
            case 4:  OperationNme.contains("hornLights")
                    vars.put("serviceType",serviceTypeVal[3]);
                     break;
            case 5:  OperationNme.contains("engineOn")
                     vars.put("serviceType",serviceTypeVal[4]);
                     break;
            case 6:  OperationNme.contains("engineOff")
                     vars.put("serviceType",serviceTypeVal[5]);
                     break;
            case 7:  OperationNme.contains("dtc")
                     vars.put("serviceType",serviceTypeVal[6]);
                     break;
            case 8:  OperationNme.contains("vrc")
                     vars.put("serviceType",serviceTypeVal[7]);
                     break;
            case 9:  OperationNme.contains("vhc")
                     vars.put("serviceType",serviceTypeVal[8]);
                     break;
            case 10: OperationNme.contains("chgPrf")
                     vars.put("serviceType",serviceTypeVal[9]);
                     break;
            case 11: OperationNme.contains("evNotif")
                     vars.put("serviceType",serviceTypeVal[10]);
                     break;
            case 12: OperationNme.contains("vehStatus")
                     vars.put("serviceType",serviceTypeVal[11]);
                     break;
            default: OperationNme.contains("Invalid Operation Name")
                     break;
        }



}
```

Comment: You should look at the actual error. To me, it looks like you forgot the semicolon on the line above (and for all `case` statements for that matter).

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems with your test:

1. `String[] serviceTypeVal = {12,19,20,21,22,23,26,27,28,31,32,11};` - is not valid declaration
2. If you switch on `OperationNme` which a string, you cannot use `case 1`, `case 2`, etc. as it is type mismatch
3. Beanshell does not support switching on strings

So you should refactor your code to look something like:

```
String OperationNme = vars.get("op");
String[] serviceTypeVal = {"12", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "26", "27", "28", "31", "32", "11"};       
if (OperationNme.contains("sdv")) {
    vars.put("serviceType", serviceTypeVal[0]);
}
if (OperationNme.contains("doorUnlock")) {
    vars.put("serviceType", serviceTypeVal[1]);
} 
// etc.
```

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting in JMeter including troubleshooting recommendations.

Actually it is recommended to use [JSR223 Test Elements](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and Groovy language for scripting. Installation is as simple as downloading [groovy-all-*.jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-all/2.4.4), dropping it into /lib folder of your JMeter installation and restarting JMeter.

After that you'll be able to select "groovy" from the "Language" drop-down, it is actively being developed and supported so it is more Java compatible than Beanshell.

Comment: Hi Dimitri, Thanks I am able to get desired result after modification of code as suggested by you however I have few questions:
1. when I am encorporating below code in java method , I am not able to execute it correctly. Can you please suggest whether beanshell support execute of code within method body  ?